# How to find specific child node in xml file using libxml2

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have an xml file like this

```
<file>
    <a>thisisa</a>
    <b>thisisb</b>
    <c>
         <c1 param1="team1" place="winner" game="cricket">
             www.team1.com
         </c1>
         <c2 param1="team2" place="runner" game="football">
             www.team2.com
         </c2>
    </c>       
</file>
```

I want to print all the games in this file using libxml2 in C. (like cricket and football in this example). I tried using xmlFirstElementChild. But this increasing the time complexity of the solution as it requires while loops. Is there any better solution to implement this?

Comment: how can I traverse to reach node "game"?

Comment: Have a look [at the tutorial](http://xmlsoft.org/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `xmlfindchild(node parent,node child ,child prop id)`.

Comment: Where is this method in libxml2? I can't find any reference to it in the documentation.